# Route to another widget while Drawer stays on the appbar

Tags: dart, flutter, drawer

I have the following drawer. it works as it should as long as i only want to hop between the widgets of my main drawer items.

[Navigation with drawer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kox3n.gif)

but inside those widgets i want to route to a new one, with a button click for example, while the drawer stays in my corner. So basically is there any way to reproduce a sticky android drawer in flutter ?

Answer (score 1):

`Drawer` is a `Scaffold` property.

So when you go to another page you will normally have another `Scaffold` widget with its own `Drawer`and the previous one will be disposed.

In the new page you need to create and display the `Drawer` for this `Scaffold` but you can't keep the previous one in the corner.

Comment: i thought about making an drawer widget that i can access in every subview scaffold but i couldn't implement it yet. probably impossible as well. i think i call it quits and concentrate on the remaining project.

Comment: A usual pattern is to create a customizable `Drawer` widget and instantiate it in the different scaffolds. You can pass callbacks to the drawer so you can have different behavior in different pages. I think the [flitter project](https://github.com/dart-flitter/flitter) implemented it in this way. Haven't checked for some time.

Answer (score 0):

Since the two widgets are `independent of each other`, you `cannot` use the same exact `Drawer` in the second widget.

Either you can create the exact copy of that `Drawer` in second one and open it on `initState` method or `if possible` instead of switching to the second, you can make the `second widget` as a `subview` inside `firstWidget`.

Comment: ok what i thought was sadly true
what would you recommend ? create a copy, make a subview or just let it be as it is and call it a feature ? are the other ones, compared to the last one, even worth the effort ?

Comment: In my opinion providing the second widget as a subview in first will be a better choise.