# How to use a 'persistant' Drawer

Tags: dart, flutter

My goal is to have a drawer for navigating between different routes.
I want to make it look a bit nicer by changing the color of the route name in the drawer if we are currently on that route.

My issue is that each time the hamburger menu is pressed a new instance of my drawer is shown because in each route I set it as:

```
return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('My Route'),
      ),
      drawer: new MyDrawer(),  //  <-----------------------------
      body: new Container()  
);
```

Is there a way to invoke the same Drawer over and over again thus keeping hold of its state?

Comment: There are many wayd to do this, and one of them is to keep the state (in a model, inherited widget, or any state management you like) and than build the drawer with that state in mind. You will have the same drawer

Comment: You may want to give a look to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50840851/route-to-another-widget-while-drawer-stays-on-the-appbar) asked recently.

Answer (score 0):

The way I did it was creating `side_nav.dart`

```cs
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluro/fluro.dart';
import '../pages/login_page.dart';
import '../pages/feedback_page.dart';
import '../pages/upload_page.dart';
import '../pages/search_orders_page.dart';

class SideNav extends StatefulWidget {
  SideNav(
    this.page,
    this.scaffoldKey, {
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);
  String page;
  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldKey;
  @override
  _SideNav createState() => new _SideNav(this.page, this.scaffoldKey);
}

class _SideNav extends State<SideNav> {
  _SideNav(this.page, this.scaffoldKey2);
  //final formKey = new GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String page;
  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldKey2;
  static Router router;
  Handler searchHandler;
  Handler settingHandler;
  Handler loginHandler;
  Handler uploadHandler;
  Handler previewHandler;

  void defineRoutes(Router router) {
    router.define("login_page", handler: loginHandler);
    router.define("setting_page", handler: settingHandler);
    router.define("search_page", handler: searchHandler);
    router.define("upload_page", handler: uploadHandler);
    router.define("page_preview", handler: previewHandler);
  }

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();

    router = new Router();
    searchHandler = new Handler(
        handlerFunc: (BuildContext context, Map<String, dynamic> params) {
      return new SearchOrdersPage();
    });
    loginHandler = new Handler(
        handlerFunc: (BuildContext context, Map<String, dynamic> params) {
      return new LoginPage();
    });
    settingHandler = new Handler(
        handlerFunc: (BuildContext context, Map<String, dynamic> params) {
      return new FeedbackPage();
    });
    uploadHandler = new Handler(
        handlerFunc: (BuildContext context, Map<String, dynamic> params) {
      return new UploadPage();
    });

    defineRoutes(router);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Drawer(
        key: scaffoldKey2,
        child: new ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            new ListTile(
              title:
                  new Text('Data store', style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0)),
              subtitle:
                  new Text('WVDEMO', style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0)),
              onTap: () {},
            ),
            new ListTile(
              title: new Text('Username', style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0)),
              subtitle: new Text('Demo', style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0)),
              onTap: () {},
            ),
            new Divider(height: 1.0, color: Colors.grey[350]),
            new ListTile(
              leading: new Icon(Icons.cloud_upload),
              title: new Text('Upload', style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0)),
              onTap: () {
                print("Page: $page");
                (page == "Upload")
                    ? Navigator.pop(context, true)
                    : router.navigateTo(
                        context,
                        "upload_page",
                        transition: TransitionType.inFromBottom,
                        replace: true,
                      );
              },
            ),
            new ListTile(
              leading: new Icon(Icons.search),
              title: new Text('Search', style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0)),
              onTap: () {
                print("Page: $page");
                (page == "Search")
                    ? Navigator.pop(context, true)
                    : router.navigateTo(
                        context,
                        "search_page",
                        transition: TransitionType.inFromBottom,
                        replace: true,
                      );
              },
            ),
            new ListTile(
              leading: new Icon(Icons.mail),
              title: new Text('Feedback', style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0)),
              onTap: () {
                print("Page: $page");
                (page == "Feedback")
                    ? Navigator.pop(context, true)
                    : router.navigateTo(
                        context,
                        "setting_page",
                        transition: TransitionType.inFromBottom,
                        replace: true,
                      );
              },
            ),
            new Divider(height: 1.0, color: Colors.grey[350]),
            new ListTile(
              title: new Text('Log Out', style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0)),
              onTap: () async {
                router.navigateTo(context, "/login_page",
                    transition: TransitionType.inFromBottom, replace: true);
              },
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

calling the drawer like this

```html
drawer: new SideNav(
        "Upload",
        scaffoldKey,
      ),
```

> There are a lot of other ways to do it. However, i found it easier to implement
>   Hope it helped